# Is there a way to program the organization of my windows on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I work everyday with the same programs (about 4-5) at the same time on three screens. I always organize my windows in the same way. To save time every morning, I was wondering if there's a way to programmatically open all my programs with the right window size, position and on the right screen.

Comment: There isn't a way to do this with Windows, so you are going to need to google for a third party tool to do it for you. They exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick google search, I have found the following solutions:

[Desksoft WindowManager](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm) (Paid - $10)

> WindowManager helps you to improve your work flow by remembering and restoring the position and size of your programs and windows. Many programs don't remember their position and size between sessions and even Windows Explorer does not restore windows to their last position under Windows 7 or higher. This is where WindowManager steps in and makes sure your windows are placed exactly where you want them every time you open them. WindowManager even allows you to lock the position and size of any window, so that it will always open at the same spot no matter where you move it.

[ShellFolderFix](http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html) (Free)

> This is an app to make win7 explorer folder windows remember their size and position. It has a couple of additional features too, and hopefully some more later on. It does NOT manage window size/positions of regular applications, if you want that, other apps like Window Manager do it. Allthough I haven't tried it, in theory it should work to run Window Manager simultaneously, if it's configured to ignore folder windows (found as "CabinetWClass"). I'd strongly recommend configuring WM to ignore them, or disable WM, before running ShellFolderFix, to avoid any potential "fighting" between the two apps.

In theory, you could make solve this in an Autohotkey script similar to this one:

```
Run, EXCEL.EXE
WinWait, Excel
WinMove, Excel,, 40, 50, 400, 500 
;40 being the X position, 50 being the Y, 400 - width and 500- height
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not believe that there is no easy solution to achieve something so dumb than resizing and remembering windows properties...

Comment: @holzi, if you feel like your question was answered, I would ask of you to mark it as answered as this helps the community know its answered!